# Add value to field using arcpy

Tags: python, arcpy, arcgis-10.1

I calculated the azimuth angle between two points. I'm trying to create a new field where I will store my angle values, but although the field is created it stays empty, no values within!

I'm using ArcGIS 10.1, the Python window. This is the code:

```
import arcpy
import math
arcpy.AddField_management("Parcelles_class_FeatureToPoi3","new_field","DOUBLE")
cur = arcpy.UpdateCursor("Parcelles_class_FeatureToPoi3") 
for row in cur :
row.getValue("POINT_X")
row.getValue("POINT_Y")
row.getValue("end_x")
row.getValue("end_y")
row.setValue("new_field", math.atan2((end_y-POINT_Y), (end_x-POINT_X)))
cur.updateRow(row)
```

Comment: Everything after `for row in cur:` should be indented -- is it correct in your code, but just pasted badly here?

Comment: No i have it like this ! i'm just new on python, can you tell me what do you mean by "indented" ?

Comment: Indented means, for example, place two spaces before each line of code to be run in the for loop. When the indentation stops that signals the end if the loop to Python. The number of spaces is not critical but you need to be consistent.

Comment: Sicne you're using 10.1, I would recommend you use [arcpy.da.UpdateCursor](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//018w00000014000000)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Python loops need to be indented (precede by 2 or 4 spaces) to [indicate to the software where the loop begins/ends](http://www.diveintopython.net/getting_to_know_python/indenting_code.html).

```
import arcpy
import math
arcpy.AddField_management("Parcelles_class_FeatureToPoi3","new_field","DOUBLE")
cur = arcpy.UpdateCursor("Parcelles_class_FeatureToPoi3") 
for row in cur :
    row.getValue("POINT_X")
    row.getValue("POINT_Y")
    row.getValue("end_x")
    row.getValue("end_y")
    row.setValue("new_field", math.atan2((end_y-POINT_Y), (end_x-POINT_X)))
    cur.updateRow(row)
```

I generally have my scripts open in some other software (e.g. Notepad++) and then copy into the Python window in order to keep all the indents properly align.

Also, you aren't setting values for the variable `end_y`, `POINT_Y` etc.

```
for row in cur:
    PointX = row.getValue("POINT_X")
    print PointX
    PointY = row.getValue("POINT_Y")
    print PointY
    EndX = row.getValue("end_x")
    print EndX
    EndY = row.getValue("end_y")
    print EndY
    azimuth = math.atan2((EndY - PointY), (EndX - PointX))
    print azimuth
    row.setValue("new_field", azimuth)
    cur.updateRow(row)
```

I've also include a print statement there so you can check that the data is being accessed correctly; feel free to remove it once you know everything's working, and then you can tighten the code up further (e.g. bring the equations back into the `row.setValue` line instead of declaring a separate variable). That can be eventually condensed into:

```
row.setValue("new_field", math.atan2((row.getValue("end_y") - row.getValue("POINT_Y")), (row.getValue("end_x") - row.getValue("POINT_X"))))
```

if you really want to conserve space :)